# Property 'isSender' cannot be accessed on 'ChatMessage?' because it is potentially null

Tags: flutter

hi i cannot pass data error showing  Property 'isSender' cannot be accessed on 'ChatMessage?' because it is potentially null. 'ChatMessage' is from 'package:getxsignup/FlutterUi/flutter_chatapp/models/chatMessage.dart' ('lib/FlutterUi/flutter_chatapp/models/chatMessage.dart').
Try accessing using ?. instead.
mainAxisAlignment: message.isSender
thank you for helping.

```
class MessagesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MessagesScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MessagesScreen> createState() => _MessagesScreenState();
}

class _MessagesScreenState extends State<MessagesScreen> {
  ChatMessage? message;



@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Row(
          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/img/user_2.png'),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: 20,
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  'Takahashi',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                ),
                Text(
                  'Active 3 minute ago',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.local_phone),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.videocam),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: kDefaultPadding / 2,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: kDefaultPadding),
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: demeChatMessages.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: message.isSender
                        ? MainAxisAlignment.end
                        : MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
```

follwing is data models

```
enum ChatMessageType { text, audio, image, video }
enum MessageStatus { not_sent, not_view, viewed }

class ChatMessage {
  final String text;
  final ChatMessageType messageType;
  final MessageStatus messageStatus;
  final bool isSender;

  ChatMessage({
    this.text = '',
    required this.messageType,
    required this.messageStatus,
    required this.isSender,
  });
}

List demeChatMessages = [
  ChatMessage(
    text: "Hi Sajol,",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.text,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.viewed,
    isSender: false,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "Hello, How are you?",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.text,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.viewed,
    isSender: true,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.audio,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.viewed,
    isSender: false,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.video,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.viewed,
    isSender: true,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "Error happend",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.text,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.not_sent,
    isSender: true,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "This looks great man!!",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.text,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.viewed,
    isSender: false,
  ),
  ChatMessage(
    text: "Glad you like it",
    messageType: ChatMessageType.text,
    messageStatus: MessageStatus.not_view,
    isSender: true,
  ),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ChatMessage` is declared as being nullable in your `State`.

You cannot build a widget depending on `message.isSender` if message can be `null`. What would the axis alignment be?

Either you handle the case that `message` is null in your build method (for example using an `if` or `message == null ? ... : ...` construct, or you declare the chat message to be not null by making it a `ChatMessage message;` in your state class. It will probably need to be `late` then since you cannot really initialize it from the constructor. It might actually be a good idea to put it in the widget instead of having it in the state for exactly this reason.

Comment: thank u for take a look my code i got little bit confusing could u show me some sample code if possible?

Comment: axis alignment  is for the chat ui sender and reciver

Comment: Do you know what the `?` in `ChatMessage? message;` means? What do you want the axis alignment to be, *if there is no chat message*?